# How to make sure when task of std::async starts?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I was reading cppreference [async#Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async#Notes)
As its `Notes` tells, I'm not really understand what it means. But as conclusion, I know that `std::async(std::launch::async, ...)` is not always starting a new thread immediatelly which runs as async.

In cppreference's example `f()` and `g()` seem running in the same thread and `g()` goes after `f()`?Is that right?

What if

```
void ff(){std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); });}
void gg(){std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); });}
int main(){
    ff();
    gg();
}
```

Would `g()` starts without waiting for `f()` complete?

All in all, how to understand what the [async#Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async#Notes) tells?Could show me more details or examples?

Comment: `is not always starting a new thread immediatelly which runs as async.` It is running, but the first `std::async` is returning `std::future`, which in the destructor will lock the main thread until the first operation will not end his job.

Comment: What does "seem running in the same thread" mean?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, `std::async(f));` (note: no lambda needed) will block until the call to `f()` has completed. That's because that call ignores the `std::future` object that the call to`async` returns; the destructor of the returned object is called immediately, and that blocks until `f()` has completed. So the task has both started and completed before the code moves on to the next statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference the full notes from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async#Notes)(emphasize mine):

> The implementation may extend the behavior of the first overload of `std::async` by enabling additional (implementation-defined) bits in the default launch policy.
>
> Examples of implementation-defined launch policies are the sync policy (execute immediately, within the `std::async` call) and the task policy (similar to `std::async`, but thread-locals are not cleared)
>
> If the `std::future` obtained from `std::async` is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the `std::future` will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, **essentially making code such as the following synchronous:**
>
> ```
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
> ```
>
> Note that the destructors of `std::futures` obtained by means other than a call to `std::async` never block.

The notes mainly point out that the `std::future` returned from the call to `std::async` blocks until the task is complete. Concerning order of evaluation, the code above is more or less equivalent to

```
 f();
 g();
```

Whether `f` and `g` are called on the same or on different threads is up to the implementation. If you want real asynchronicity you must keep the returned future:

```
 auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); });
 auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); });
```

Only then you get asynchronous calls and either `g` or `f` is called first. Whether they are called on the same thread or not is still up to the implementation.

Nowhere they say that `f` and `g` are necessarily called on the same thread and it is wrong to conclude that. It is possible to write multithreaded code without concurrency and without asynchronous calls. Usually thats not what you want, hence the notes point out the importance of the returned `std::future`.